# Get page content of a page which is using a form-based authentication

Tags: php, plugins

Recently, I have succeeded to get the content of a wiki page using JSON Plugin:

```
        $username = '****';
        $password = '****';
        $sc = new Serverclient_helper();
        $login = "http://********/api.php?action=login&lgname=$username&lgpassword=$password";
        $content = $sc->getContent($login,array(),false);   

        $host = "http://******/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=Main";
        $content = $sc->getContent($host);
        $content = json_decode($content);
```

Today I have tried to do the same, but with another page which requires login too, like the wiki page. It wasn't successful. I think it is because of the fact that this page has not structure of a wiki page. [Here something to wiki pages.](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page) I have read a lot and I understood that my page is using a form based authentication. But I still want to know how to access the whole content of the page.

I have also used [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-setopt.php), but it hasn't helped me to get the content. Only the login page was diplayed, but I wasn't logged in.

Here is my code:

```
$username='*****';
$password='*****';
$location='http://*****/startphp';


$mycurl = curl_init ();
curl_setopt($mycurl,CURLOPT_URL,$location);
curl_setopt($mycurl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($mycurl,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"$username:$password");
curl_setopt($mycurl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

$result = curl_exec ($mycurl); 
var_dump($result);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CURLOPT_USERPWD` is only for Basic HTTP Authentication.

You will need to use `POST` commands that match up with the service.

```
$data = array('username' => 'User', 'password' => 'Pass');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

And you will also need to look into storing the `SESSION` the site provides you

with `CURLOPT_COOKIE` `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options

Comment: Thank you, @Christopher Morrissey! :) Have a nice day!